# How to calculate the value of this integral?

Tags: integration

$$
\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{c-x^{2}(1-d\, x)}}
$$

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the d in the square root a constant?

Comment: It is elliptic integral which cannot be expressed as elementary function in general.

Comment: @LaplacianFourier, $a, b, c$ and $d$ are constants.

Comment: @See-WooLee. It is not only an elliptic integral. It is a monster !!!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Why is it a monster? Do you mean it can't be solved?